# Sending POST request from Unity WebGL to HTTPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post, https

I am sending a POST request from a HTTPS page to the following URL:

```
https://example.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mydemomodule&controller=display
```

This is the code I use:

```
IEnumerator CaptureScreenshotAndPost()
{
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("hello", "yellow");
    form.AddBinaryData("fileToUpload", imageBytes, "screenShot.png", "image/png");
    UnityWebRequest www1 = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://example.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mydemomodule&controller=display", form);

    yield return www1.Send();

    if (www1.isNetworkError || www1.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www1.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Upload completed!");
    }
}
```

When the code from above executes, the following error is thrown.

> Mixed Content: The page at '`https://www.example.com/index.php?fc=module&module= mydemomodule&controller=display`' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '`http://www.example.com/index.php?fc=module&module= mydemomodule&controller=display?fc=module&module= mydemomodule&controller=display`'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My request was to `https://example.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mydemomodule&controller=display`, but  the domain have redirect to **www**.example.com, so it redirects it to the **HTTP**-page with www
`http://www.example.com/index.php?fc=module&module=mydemomodule&controller=display`